# Create a new table for each registered member

Tags: java, php

How could i include in the include.php file that whenever the code is set there is also another function added, which would be something like:

```
 $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS (here would be post parameter email from java file) (
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        DATE    DATETIME NOT NULL,
        PAIN INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    )"
```

So this means when a user clicks register he would be added to the users table and also a new table would be created where the name of the table would be his email!

include.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    // receiving the post params
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];



    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // user already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Uporabnik že obstaja " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // create a new user
        $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Neznana napaka!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Manjkajo paramatri (name, email or password)!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Any help or ideas on how to implement that would be very helpfull.

Comment: are you talking about running a sql query for the `CREATE TABLE...`

Comment: sure that `java` is the right tag here? Maybe you meant `mysql`?

Comment: i added Java since i am getting my data from android java program, where user puts input, if you still think its inapropriate i will remove

Answer (score 1):

You need backticks to enclose your table name, because the `@`-sign will lead to non syntax-conform table name:

```
$query = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{$_POST["email"]}` (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    DATE    DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PAIN INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
)"
```

I gracefully assume, that $_POST["email"] has been checked on sanity beforehand.

Comment: I guess this is the answer to the question? +1

Comment: I randomly put in some characters and some text appeared ;-) Yes, it is the answer, of course, although i bet that the resulting product will be very... strange. No idea why someone would want to do that, but ok